# Getting hung up in a BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I've got an app that checks every few seconds for new orders.
If it sees a new entry in the database, it fires off a `BackgroundWorker` to process it.

I have 3 list boxes on my form, pending, completed and failed.

Theres is a second `BackgroundWorker` process which asynchronously checks with an api to see if the order has been fully processed yet, before moving the item in question to the 'completed' list box.

Everything seems to be working fine until I throw a few orders at a time at the app.

It processes the orders fine and adds them to pending, and it will check back on a few of them but eventually get stuck in the secondbackground worker process.
It will eventually crash out with a `"This BackgroundWorker is currently busy"` error.

I've gone over my code lots of times and I can't see where it would be crashing out. 
Whats the best way for me to diagnose this?

Heres the code for the background worker where I'm getting stuck...

```
Private Sub BuildProgressCheck_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
    Handles BuildProgressCheck.DoWork

    lblstatus.Text = "Checking back on async jobs"

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To buildpendinglist.Items.Count - 1
        Beep()

        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=" & dbserver & "; userid=" & dbusername & "; password=" & dbpassword & "; database=" & dbdatabase & ";Convert Zero Datetime=True"
        Dim jobcheck As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM dbcpman_jobs WHERE dbxid='" & buildpendinglist.Items(i) & "'", cn)
        Dim jobcheck_table As New DataTable
        jobcheck.Fill(jobcheck_table)
        Dim jobrow As DataRow
        jobrow = jobcheck_table.Select("failed = 'false'").FirstOrDefault()

        If Not jobrow Is Nothing Then

            Dim job_id As String = jobrow.Item("id")
            Dim job_jobid As String = jobrow.Item("jobid")
            Dim job_status As String = jobrow.Item("status")
            Dim job_dbxid As String = jobrow.Item("dbxid")
            Dim jobcommand As String = "command=queryAsyncJobResult&jobId=" & job_jobid
            Dim fulljobapicheckurl = cpapiurl & jobcommand

            Try
                Dim jobapicall As New System.Net.WebClient
                jobcheckresult = jobapicall.DownloadString(fulljobapicheckurl)

            Catch ex As Exception
                ''Problem submitting the api request?
            End Try

            If jobcheckresult.Contains("<jobstatus>1</jobstatus>") Then  ''If true, job has completed

                Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
                doc.LoadXml(jobcheckresult) ''api_result contains xml returned from a http request.

                If doc.GetElementsByTagName("virtualmachine") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim elem As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("virtualmachine").Item(0).ChildNodes
                    For Each item As XmlNode In elem
                        If item.Name.Equals("state") Then
                            new_vm_state += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("hostname") Then
                            new_vm_hostname += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("templatename") Then
                            new_vm_templatename += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("cpunumber") Then
                            new_vm_cpunumber += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("cpuspeed") Then
                            new_vm_cpuspeed += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("memory") Then
                            new_vm_memory += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("nic") Then
                            new_vm_netmask += ((item.ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                            new_vm_gateway += ((item.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                            new_vm_ipaddress += ((item.ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                            new_vm_macaddress += ((item.ChildNodes.Item(11).InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        ElseIf item.Name.Equals("instancename") Then
                            new_vm_instancename1 += ((item.InnerText.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                new_vm_macaddress = new_vm_macaddress.ToUpper
                Dim privateip As String = new_vm_ipaddress.Replace(" ", "").ToString
                Dim publicip As String = privateip.Replace("172.16.11.", "198.73.112.")

                Try
                    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
                    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim SQL As String
                    myCommand.Connection = cn
                    cn.Open()
                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    SQL = "DELETE FROM dbcpman_jobs WHERE jobid = '" & job_jobid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQL = "UPDATE dbcpman_vm SET deployresponse = '" & jobcheckresult & "' WHERE dbx_id = '" & job_dbxid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQL = "UPDATE dbcpman_vm SET macaddress = '" & new_vm_macaddress & "' WHERE dbx_id = '" & job_dbxid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQL = "UPDATE dbcpman_vm SET publicip = '" & publicip & "' WHERE dbx_id = '" & job_dbxid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQL = "UPDATE dbcpman_vm SET privateip = '" & privateip & "' WHERE dbx_id = '" & job_dbxid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    cn.Close()

                    Dim new_vm_username As String = "clouduser"
                    Dim new_vm_password As String = GeneratePassword(7)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    Dim new_vm_support_username As String = "dbxsupport"
                    Dim new_vm_support_password As String = GenerateSupportPassword(7)

                    cn.Open()
                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    SQL = "INSERT into dbcpman_credentials(username1, username2, password1, password2, type, link) VALUES ('" & new_vm_username & "','" & new_vm_support_username & "','" & new_vm_password & "','" & new_vm_support_password & "','Server root logon','" & job_dbxid & "')"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQL = "INSERT into dbcpman_vm_boot(dbxid, ip, macaddress, hostname) VALUES ('" & job_dbxid & "','" & new_vm_ipaddress & "','" & new_vm_macaddress & "','" & job_dbxid & "')"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cn.Close()

                    Try  ''''add monitoring for this new host
                        Dim monitorurl As String = "http://192.168.16.32/addhost.php?hostname=" & job_dbxid & "&ipaddr=" & publicip
                        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
                        Dim monresult As String = webClient.DownloadString(monitorurl)
                        If monresult = "SUCCESS" Then
                            ''success message
                        Else
                            ''fail message

                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try

                    buildcompletedlist.Items.Add(buildpendinglist.Items(i))
                    buildpendinglist.Items.Remove(buildpendinglist.Items(i))

                    buildprogresscheckactive = 0
                    BuildProgressCheck.CancelAsync()

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            ElseIf jobcheckresult.Contains("<jobstatus>0</jobstatus>") Then  ''If true, job is still pending
                ''job still pending - do nothing, will check again on next pass

            ElseIf jobcheckresult.Contains("<jobstatus>2</jobstatus>") Then  ''If true, job has failed
                Try
                    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
                    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim SQL As String
                    myCommand.Connection = cn
                    cn.Open()
                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    SQL = "UPDATE dbcpman_jobs SET failed = 'true' WHERE jobid = '" & job_jobid & "'"
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cn.Close()

                    buildfailedlist.Items.Add(buildpendinglist.Items(i))
                    buildpendinglist.Items.Remove(buildpendinglist.Items(i))
                                        Catch ex As Exception
                    BuildProgressCheck.CancelAsync()
                    buildprogresscheckactive = 0
                End Try

            End If
        End If

    Next
    buildprogresscheckactive = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't test it now but BuildProgressCheck.CancelAsync() is never called when "job still pending". What happens if that job remains in pending?. I mean if the job goes Pending forever, the next run BuildProgressCheck BW will be busy.

Comment: Show the code where you create the background worker and run it.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess based on the appended text and code is as follows:

- *`"..checks every few seconds for new orders."`*
- Error: *`"This BackgroundWorker is currently busy"`*

So I believe you're starting the asynchronous work in a `Tick` event of a `Timer`. So, let's say your timer ticks every 2 seconds.

```
Friend WithEvents mytimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer With {.Interval = 2000, .Enabled = True}

Private Sub _Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mytimer.tick
    Me.BuildProgressCheck.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Now, lets imagine that for 6 ticks `BuildProgressCheck_DoWork` are executed in `less than 2 seconds`. No error occurs and everything seems okay. But, at the 7th tick it take `3 seconds`. Then, when the timer raise tick for the 8th time, the `BackGroundWorker` is `"currently busy"` and throws an error.

What you need to do is to suspend the timer before running the worker and resume it when the worker has completed. Here's an example:

```
Private Sub _Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mytimer.Tick
    'Suspend the timer:
    Me.mytimer.Enabled = False
    'Do background work:
    Me.BuildProgressCheck.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub _DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BuildProgressCheck.DoWork
    'Important: Do not invoke any UI controls inside this method.
    '           (We're inside the background thread)
End Sub

Private Sub _ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BuildProgressCheck.ProgressChanged
    'Here you can safely invoke UI controls.
    '(We're inside UI thread)
    'Me.Label1.Text = "Started..."
End Sub

Private Sub _RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BuildProgressCheck.RunWorkerCompleted
    Try
        If (e.Error Is Nothing) Then
            If (e.Cancelled) Then
                'Cancelled
            Else
                'Success
            End If
        Else
            'Error
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        '...
    Finally
        'Restart the timer.
        Me.mytimer.Enabled = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this in the morning and see.
I do sort of suspend the timer, or rather use an if statement to decide whether to fire off the backgroundworker.